# Why does the Google App Engine warn me 'file referenced by handler not found : dailybasic.py' again and again?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, yaml

I'm coding with the GAE in python, and I tried to make two script files. So I make the app.yaml like this:

```
application: mathgirlna
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /dailybasic/.*
  script: /dailybasic.py
  login: admin

- url: /.*
  script: main.py
```

And when I see the logs, it says 'file referenced by handler not found : dailybasic.py'. I have no idea how the app.yaml have to be written.

Here's my file tree:

- static

  - index.css
- app.yaml
- index.yaml
- cron.yaml
- index.html
- main.py
- dailybasic.py

I'm also hesitating with this tree. Should I move these files?

And last, I've not installed the python library 'ssl'. Could it be a reason of this error?

Comment: Can you show us your complete app.yaml, please? Also, do you get this on the dev server, or just in production?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `'/'` in `script: /dailybasic.py`.

```
- url: /dailybasic/.*
  script: dailybasic.py
  login: admin
```

Comment: This was an absolute cherry pick, I know, but I better get that bloody tick :)

Comment: lol. Do you wanna show your def main(): in dailybasic.py also?

Comment: Are you still getting the same error? 'file referenced by handler not found'?

Comment: Yes, same error. And dailybasic.py does the completely different process. It posts a tweet every 5 minutes(using the cron.yaml). And main.py prints the html file, and that's all it does.

Comment: Can you pastebin the complete yaml file?

Comment: Are you calling run_wsgi_app() in both files?

Comment: That's suspicious. Could there be a leading or trailing space in the real file name?

Comment: @Kevin Yes. And they are separated: not importing each other.
    
    `webapp.WSGIApplication([('/dailybasic', dailybasic)], debug=True)`

for dailybasic.py, 
    
    `webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)`

for main.py.

Comment: @DrewSears Exactly not. It's 'dailybasic.py'.