# File referenced by handler not found: main.application

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I keep getting this error when I try to run my application. My app.yaml is :

```
application: xxxapplication
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /.*
  script: main.py

libraries:
- name: django
  version: "1.3"
- name: jinja2
  version: latest

builtins:
- remote_api: on
```

and my directory tree looks like this:

```
main.py
templates
static
app.yaml
```

I know this has been asked before in: [Why does the Google App Engine warn me 'file referenced by handler not found : dailybasic.py' again and again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365084/why-does-the-google-app-engine-warn-me-file-referenced-by-handler-not-found-d)

but that doesn't seem to solve my problem. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The handlers with python27 runtime must be of the type: `module.obj`. In your case the module is `main` (the name of the python file) and the obj is the wsgi obj inside the module (main.py ), most likely `application`.

```
- url: /.*
script: main.application
```

Comment: Note that if your handler is inside a package the label will have to read...script: package.module.app

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. My issue was due to filenaming (e.g., Picture.jpg versus picture.jpg). I removed all of the capital letters in my file names and "Static file referenced by handler not found" went away from my logs.

Thanks to: http://grokbase.com/t/gg/google-appengine/132m5gkxf8/some-static-images-not-uploaded-but-they-are-shown-in-local